# integrate smarty with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I am a very beginner to codeigniter framework and smarty template.

I want to integrate the smarty template with the codeigniter framework.
I followed the link http://sunwebexpert.com/books/detail/PHP/integrating-smarty-and-codeigniter.html

And I got an error like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'index.tpl' <-- thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniterNew\application\libraries\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 129
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a 'index.tpl' file in views/templates directory ?

Comment: now i got the answer that,my index.tpl file was not present in views/templates directory .   i changed that path in smarty.php file in application/libraries/smarty.php file                                                            $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH.'view');
        $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH.'views');